# Share everything except cloud storage on family plan

Tags: icloud, sharing, family-sharing

Is there a way to share only specific services to family members? My daughter will fill the cloud storage up quickly with nonsense if I share that.

I do want to share TV, Music, and other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Share everything except cloud storage on family plan

**Yes, you can do this.**

You can manage a number of things like iCloud storage. From [Share iCloud+ with your family](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208147):

> If a family member is already paying for their own iCloud+ plan, they can choose to switch to your plan or keep their own and still remain part of the family.

It’s not elegant; individual storage quotas would be ideal.  However, you can get an individual storage plan for your daughter at 99 cents per month (current cost at time of this post) and allow her to fill it up to her heart’s content without affecting your storage limits.

See What is [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) for a comprehensive guide to what you can do with A family plan.